# apache rockerMQ broker doesn't start

Tags: apache, rocketmq

i try to star rockerMQ broker,but i got the error message:

> ## There is insufficient memory for the Java Runtime Environment to continue.
>
> ## Native memory allocation (mmap) failed to map 8589934592 bytes for committing reserved memory.
>
> ## An error report file with more information is saved as:
>
> ## /usr/local/soft/rocketMQ/incubator-rocketmq/distribution/target/apache-rocketmq/hs_err_pid6034.log
>
> Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: INFO: os::commit_memory(0x00000005c0000000, 8589934592, 0) failed; error='Cannot allocate memory' (errno=12)

and i got something from the error log file about message of memory:

> Memory: 4k page, physical 4089840k(551832k free), swap 2621432k(2621432k free)
>   vm_info: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.144-b01) for linux-amd64 JRE (1.8.0_144-b01), built on Jul 21 2017 21:57:33 by "java_re" with gcc 4.3.0 20080428 (Red Hat 4.3.0-8)

how can i let the rockerMQ broker working for me

Answer (score 5):

You can reduce the JVM heap size.
Open the *distribution/bin/runbroker.sh* file of your project and change the following line

JAVA_OPT="${JAVA_OPT} -server -Xms8g -Xmx8g -Xmn4g"

as

JAVA_OPT="${JAVA_OPT} -server -Xms4g -Xmx4g -Xmn2g"

now broker will only generate a 4G heap .I hope it will solve your problem.Now you can try to build and run.

Answer (score 0):

Try modifying the start shell scripts to make a smaller JVM heap size in your dev/test env